# Binary transfer using bluetooth android--(OBEX)

Tags: android, bluetooth, binary-data, obex

I need to transfer binary data through bluetooth in android.
Should I use OBEX for it or is there any other way of doing it.

Please suggest me a tutorial/link for the same.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Bluetooth SPP profile, 
Android has good documentation and example code here .[Setting up Bluetooth](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#SettingUp)

Comment: But I wanted to try OBEX.. Can some one tell me how to use this. I have downloaded the open source but need to know how exactly to use it.

Comment: guys please suggest me a way of transferring a binary file over bluetooth

Answer (score 0):

The standard method of Bluetooth file transfer employs OBEX over RFCOMM, providing an FTP service/profile. OBEX is a binary/object exchange protocol from the IrDA association, and is fairly easy to implement but very scalable and generic. Also, multiple libraries are available on the internet if you don't want to code from scratch via the specs. Whether you want to target the full-blown FTP or the simpler OPP, you will anyway need OBEX as underlying layer.